# submission of array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Assuming the following string of parameters which is composed of an array of hashes, what is the proper way to submit them to Rails

```
&auth=6db2f8aa0af80748&guest={surname:"Tizio",name:"Caio",type:"A"}&guest={surname:"Cane",name:"Pippo",type:"B"}&guest={surname:"Topo",name:"Giggio",type:"C"}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your string looks like says that it's about passing parameters in the query string of GET request.

To pass array of hashes you can use this syntax:

```
&auth=6db2f8aa0af80748&guest[][surname]=Tizio&guest[][name]=Caio&guest[][type]=A&guest[][surname]=Cane&guest[][name]=Pippo&guest[][type]=B&guest[][surname]=Topo&guest[][name]=Giggio&guest[][type]=C
```

On the server this string is interpreted as:

```
>> Parameters: {"auth"=>"6db2f8aa0af80748", "guest"=>[{"surname"=>"Tizio", "name"=>"Caio", "type"=>"A"}, {"surname"=>"Cane", "name"=>"Pippo", "type"=>"B"}, {"surname"=>"Topo", "name"=>"Giggio", "type"=>"C"}]}
```

While parsing query string, Rails interprets `guest` as an array because of `[]` following `guest`. `guest[][surname]` makes it create a hash with a key `surname` and add it to array `guest`. Next param `guest[][name]` is interpreted as part of a hash too, but instead of creating a new hash it will add this key-value pair to the last hash from `guest`. Other params will be added to that hash until the key which already exists in the hash is met. In this case a new hash will be created and added.

Comment: > but instead of creating a new hash it will add this key-value pair to the last hash from guest.

Is there a way to get a hash every time (meaning every hash in the array has just one key-value pair) ?